# Where is the viewRenderer actually set?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I understand that viewRenderer is a built in action controller helper, but where exactly is this set?  I see that when the action controller is instantiated, it creates the helper broker, which iterates over the Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker_PriorityStack, which already has the viewRenderer within it.  But how did the viewRenderer get set within the helper broker priority stack?  As always, thx for taking the time out to read my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I now see that it's set within Zend_Application_Resource_View if you bootstrap Zend_View, and within the front controller if you don't.